Meaning of the chengyu 生民塗炭
君王的行為使的生民塗炭。
生民塗炭 is a chengyu. It means the populace is living in misery.
However I don't understand exactly what 塗炭 literally means. 炭 means coal. 塗 I only understand as a verb; to paint, to smear etc.
There is also a definition of 泥塗, which means a mud-clogged road. But then even in this phrase 塗 seems to represent road and not mud (but I'm not sure).
If 塗 means mud, then the chengyu 生民塗炭 means people are in mud and burning in coal = living in abject misery. So I suppose my question is what does 塗 really mean here? Thanks.

生民塗炭 is a variant of  生靈塗炭 which is the standard form of this idiom

生靈(the living and conscious) refers to 人民、百姓 ( the common people), as well as living and conscious creatures

塗 = quagmire (mud)

炭 = charcoal (fire)



「生靈塗炭」 "Life is in ruins"

"People are trapped in a quagmire and charcoal fire", a metaphor for the extreme plight of the people.
In modern Chinese, 生靈塗炭 mostly refers to "massive lives lost and suffering"

塗炭 - coal fire mixed with mud. It creates "a dirty and difficult condition/environment", and means "in utter misery".
BTW, I think the original phrase was "民生涂炭" or "生灵涂炭".
